# Android Studio can't open .graphql file

Tags: android, android-studio, graphql

I am working on an android project that works with a graphql server. The problem is that the android studio can't open .graphql file. It doesn't show any error but it just doesn't open it. I have to open another text editor and modify .graphql file, and it builds without an error, but it is very weird that my android studio can't handle .graphql file. Is there any way that I can edit graphql file on android studio?

Answer (score 5):

I removed graphql from Settings-Editor-FileTypes/Files opened in associated applications, and now it works fine.